# Donde puedo simular una app en un dispositivo en concreto

Tags: android, emulación

Tengo una aplicación en producción y un usuario me ha informado que tiene problemas con una determinada actividad. Mirando el código no veo nada raro y en los dispositivos con los que he testeado la aplicación funciona   correctamente.

Este usuario tiene un Huawei P20 ¿Como puedo emular la app en un dispositivo como ese de manera virtual?

¿Como testeais vosostros este tipo de fallos?

Comment: Has probado la apps en un dispositivo con Android 8.0 (Oreo) o solo es en el dispositivo especificado?

Comment: No vas a poder emular lo que pasa en un dispositivo especifico, lo mas cerca que vas a estar es levantar un emulador con la misma version de Android, pero aun asi, cada fabricante realiza sus propias modificaciones al Sistema Operativo

Comment: En que emuladores pruebas tu? en `AVD` de `AndroidStudio`? o en `GenyMotion`?

Comment: Emulo con el AVD de Android Studio. Esta persona tiene la versión 8.1 de android y a mi me funciona bien en el emulador con la API 27.

Comment: Genymotion dispone de muchos modelos de moviles que puede emular. Hay una version gratuita que te puedes descargar y probar desde Android Studio y Visual Studio. Espero sea de ayuda..